# BindableBase - SetProperty does not work using the instance of the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to set the property of the MainViewModel from LoginViewModel using an instance of the MainViewModel inside LoginViewModel . But the binding in XAML does not get notified ! I set the break point inside the MainViewModel and  it shows the value is being set, but if its set through instance it does not work. Can anyone help?
Below are the codes for both viewmodel. As you can see, in my loginviewmodel I set the public property using the instance of MainViewModel :

```
MainViewModel.Instance.Mainviewpageindex = 1;
```

MainViewModel

```
namespace DataRetrieval.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private static MainViewModel _instance = new MainViewModel();
        public static MainViewModel Instance { get { return _instance; }


        }

        private int _mainviewpageindex;
        public int Mainviewpageindex
        {
            get { 
                return _mainviewpageindex; }
            set { 
               SetProperty(ref _mainviewpageindex, value);
              //  _mainviewpageindex = value;
               // RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Mainviewpageindex");
            } 
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Mainviewpageindex = 0;

        }

          public DelegateCommand<object> _loginCommand;
          public ICommand LoginCommand
          {
              get
              {
                  _loginCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(Login, VerifyLogin);
                  return _loginCommand;
              }
          }
            private void Login(object context)
            {
                Mainviewpageindex = 1;
            }


            private bool VerifyLogin(object context)
            {
                return true;
            }

    }
```

LoginViewModel

```
namespace DataRetrieval.ViewModels
{

        public class LoginViewModel : BindableBase
        {
          //  public SecureString SecurePassword { private get; set; }
            private string _uname;
            public string Uname
            {
                get { return _uname; }
                set { 
                    SetProperty(ref _uname, value);
                   _loginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

                }
            }
            private SecureString _securePassword;
            public SecureString SecurePassword
            {
                get { return _securePassword; }
                set {
                    SetProperty(ref _securePassword, value);
                    _loginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                }
            }

            public LoginViewModel()
            {

            }

            public DelegateCommand<object> _loginCommand;
            public ICommand LoginCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    _loginCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(Login, VerifyLogin);
                    return _loginCommand;
                }
            }

            private void Login(object context)
            {
                if (SecurePassword != null || Uname != null)
                {
                    //PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
                   // bool validated = ctx.ValidateCredentials(Uname, SecureStringToString(SecurePassword));
                  MainViewModel.Instance.Mainviewpageindex = 1;

                }else
                {

                }

            }
            String SecureStringToString(SecureString value)
            {
                IntPtr valuePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
                try
                {
                    valuePtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(value);
                    return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(valuePtr);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(valuePtr);
                }
            }

            private bool VerifyLogin(object context)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataRetrieval.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DataRetrieval.Views"
           xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
          xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:DataRetrieval.ViewModels"
        Title="Data Retrieval Tool" Height="Auto" Width="900" Icon="Resources/colorful_query_mark_light_bulb_28261523_y2o_icon.ico">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TabControl Name="TabControl1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="White" SelectedIndex="{Binding Mainviewpageindex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TabItem Header="General">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="300"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <views:Login HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Text="User your OneAbbott domain user name and password to login into the system" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                <Button  x:Name="btnLogin" Content="Login" Margin="20" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
            </Grid>



        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Second Tab">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Login Successfull" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>


            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: are you sure your XAML is fine? Looks like you tried using `RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Mainviewpageindex")` and it worked? If it did not then there is a high chance that the binding in your XAML is wrong.

Comment: @KingKing  Thanks for the reply, I also included the XAML so you can see. RaisePropertyChangedEvent did not work either, but I know xaml is fine, because I can set Mainviewpageindex using a button and command inside the same MainViewModel. Only from another view model does not work !

Comment: Are there any Data Binding errors in the output window?

Comment: You set the `DataContext` to an instance of your view-model right in XAML, but then in code you set the property of another instance (the singleton instance), so it cannot update back to your ui.

Comment: @KingKing so what is the solution if I want to set the Mainviewpageindex from another viewmodel? do you have any sample code?

Comment: Change your XAML to this `<Window .... DataContext="{x:Static viewmodels:MainViewModel.Instance}">` ***or*** in code you don't use `Instance` (which means it's redundant).

Comment: @Gusdor thanks for your comment. No there is not any error there.

Comment: @KingKing get the following error : MainViewModel is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.

Comment: well you should be able to correct it, I wrote `viewmodels:` but it should be `viewModels:` (that namespace is yours).

Comment: @KingKing I do not think the syntax is correct. Sorry man.

Comment: do you mean it does not work? please update what you edited to your XAML.

Comment: @KingKing  The top part of XAML is updated to this :  <Window x:Class="DataRetrieval.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DataRetrieval.Views"
           xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
        DataContext="{x:Static ViewModels:MainViewModel.Instance}"
          xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:DataRetrieval.ViewModels"
        Title="Data Retrieval Tool" Height="Auto" Width="900" ">

Comment: you wrote `ViewModels:` but it should be `viewModels:`

Comment: @KingKing  I get this error if I write viewModels:  --->The name "MainViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:DataRetrieval.ViewModels".

Comment: It's strange you obviously declare `MainViewModel` in that namespace. Have you tried running your project anyway? Don't trust in what the XAML editor notifies to you.

Comment: @KingKing yes I know I can not trust the errors there, I tried to run but still does not recognize it !

Comment: your XAML posted in the comment has 3 semi-colons (at the end of each) in this `xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";` and this `xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";` and this `xmlns:prism="codeplex.com/prism";`. That will cause invalid syntax. You should double check it again.

Comment: @KingKing I belive those are added by stackoverflow  when I copy paste ! my code does not have it. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: There must be some problem on your side. With what I suggested to you, it should work and if not there should not be any error at design time (so that it does not compile), you should double-check it. The syntax here is very straight-forward by using `{x:Static}`, `MainViewModel` is clearly defined in that namespace, so no reason for such error to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best way to implement the communication between ModelViews is using prism Event Aggregation !

An example of it is provided here on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921173(v=pandp.40).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with two different instances of your MainViewModel. The one actually hooked up to your view is constructed by the XAML parser when it hits the code that is setting your data context.

The other you are creating as a separate static object inside your viewmodel and exposing through the Instance property.

You need a different way to communicate between the ViewModel instances. Pub-Sub events in Prism are the best way to deal with this kind of scenario, although using a CompositeCommand would also work.

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant using "Event Aggregation" in prism . Yes seems that one is the best way.